# Selenium: do javascript actions reflect in driver.page_source?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

If I click on a button that executes some javascript that updates the page (e.g. adds some html somewhere), will this be reflected in driver.page_source?

I tried it (clicked on a button that executed some js), waited 10 seconds, and then took a look at driver.page_source and changes do not seem to show up there. How can I find out what html was created by that js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, driver.page_source only gives static html code.
If you want html created by js, you may use

```
driver.execute_script()
```

It runs js script and returns the result. Here is an example:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='WB_feed_type SW_fun S_line2']") #which is created by js
wbHTML = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element)
```